# Software to create perspective line with curves

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, software-recommendation, perspective, autocad

What software and tools can I use to quickly create lines over single or multiple photographs that have the effect of disappearing into the distance? Sometimes the line would need to have curves. I would also like the line to reduce opacity as it disappears in the distance.

Take the following base image for example:

[image: Example picture]

The very crude hand drawn example below shows how I would like the line to curve in line with the road. However, I would like the line to be wider in the foreground and become narrower as it disappears in the distance.

[image]

The following screenshot shows a one point perspective grid in Adobe Illustrator with a rectangle drawn. I am unsure how to add curves and reduce the opacity over the length of the line. I have tried using the line tool in Ilustrator and increasing the width but this does not work. Rather than drawing a rectangle am I able to draw a line with curves but still obtain the desired effects?

[image]

What software packages would enable me to quickly and efficiently perform these tasks over single and multiple photographs?

I have access to a variety of software packages including Autocad, Adobe Illustrator and Inkscape but would consider purchasing other packages.

Comment: Both answers below are very helpful and informative, thank you. I have now also discovered another method in Illustrator which I think is more suited to my needs. Am i able to accept both answers below and also post my method as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to Danielillo's excellent answer, something similar is also possible using Inkscape's Interpolate extension.

[image]

Reducing the opacity of lines in the distance could be achieved using a mask, made from a gradient.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With Illustrator

- Make two irregular lines at the border of the street

[image: lines]

- Select both lines, **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Make**
- **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Blend Options** > **Specified Steps** = number
- Stroke the blend with a linear gradient

  - From black to black
  - From 100% to 0% opacity
  - Angle=90%
  - Move the Gradient Slider
- **Direct Selection Tool**, select a vertex and move the **Live Corners widgets** to round it, do the same with the other vertex

[image: way]